Каламбур ли это?
«Школько товаров к школе купить» (школько = сколько). Это использование каламбура или чего-то другого?

использование шепелявости?

ну нет) там «школько» = школа + сколько. но это и не каламбур вроде бы, и не ирония...

соединение двух слов в одно - это сленг, но тут соединения не вижу

Но вообще, если считаете, что здесь имеет место быть взаимодействие слов, то это "игра слов".

Главное — зачем изменять слова? Вы сможете объяснить свой выбор?

это было в рекламе. идея не моя)

Это ирония. Как то: ну, не шмогла; на шонце шилиндром шверкая; дефочка/фефочка (смысл этих фраз, надеюсь, известен). В тексте от лица автора ирония или самоирония безобидна, но в других случаях, переходя рамки, она превращается в насмешку и сатиру. Многое зависит от контекста.
